# AngularJS Passing a promise into $mdDialog locals

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable of type `angular.IPromise<any>` and I pass in into my dialog through `locals`. ex: `dialogOptions.locals = {data: promiseData}`. I resolve the promise in my controller since I want the dialog to appear even if the data hasn't been processed yet. However, it still looks like it's waiting for the promise to be resolved before the dialog opens. Why is this happening?

Comment: did you tried to pass data using mddialog resolve instead of locals

Comment: I believe resolve doesn't open the dialog until the promises are resolved. Is there any way I can pass in the promise and have the dialog open while it's fetching the data?